# How to handle neverending matches from user-submitted regexes

Tags: c#, .net, regex, user-input

Let's consider the two following lines in C# (using framework .NET 3.5)

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^((E|e)t )?(M|m)oi (?<NewName>[A-Za-z]\.?\w*((\-|\s)?[A-Za-z]?\w{1,})+)$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = regex.Match("moi aussi jaimerai etre un ordinateur pour pas m'énnerver ");
```

(sorry it's a french program :))

When they are executed, the process gets stuck in the `Match()` method and never exits. I guess there is some problem with the white space in the regex pattern but what I would like to do is not changing the pattern (actually it is set outside the program, by the end users of my tool) but being able to stop the process (with a timeout for instance).

Does someone know if this is well-known problem with the .NET Regular Expression and if there is an easy way to work around it or do I have to thread these lines and abort them if needed (definitely I wouldn't like to do that).

Comment: No, it's a well-known problem with letting users enter their own regular expressions. :-/

Comment: Pb.NET ? Is that the french version of VB.NET ? Sorry, I'm still to learn both those languages. :P

Comment: @PierrOz: Your question appears to be misleading. It is not about the Regex. It is about the process and how to abort it if it takes too long. But all the answers you are going to get will tell you how to optimize your Regex. To my mind, that's not what you are asking.

Comment: I went ahead and fixed that title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should simply launch the Regex match on a separate thread and allow it to be aborted if a certain maximum time limit is reached.

Answer (score 4):

If I enter the expression in Regexbuddy, it presents following message

> The match attempt was aborted early
>   because the regular expression is too
>   complex. The regex engine you plan to
>   use it with may not be able to handle
>   it at all and crash. Look up
>   "catastrophic backtracking" in the
>   help file to learn how to avoid this
>   situation.

Looking up **catastrophic backtracking** gives the following explanation

> **Runaway Regular Expressions: Catastrophic Backtracking**
>   Consider the regular expression (x+x+)+y.
>   Before you scream in horror and say
>   this contrived example should be
>   written as xx+y to match exactly the
>   same without those terribly nested
>   quantifiers: just assume that each "x"
>   represents something more complex,
>   with certain strings being matched by
>   both "x". See the section on HTML
>   files below for a real example.
>
> Let's see what happens when you apply
>   this regex to xxxxxxxxxxy. The first
>   x+ will match all 10 x characters. The
>   second x+ fails. The first x+ then
>   backtracks to 9 matches, and the
>   second one picks up the remaining x.
>   The group has now matched once. The
>   group repeats, but fails at the first
>   x+. Since one repetition was
>   sufficient, the group matches. y
>   matches y and an overall match is
>   found. The regex is declared
>   functional, the code is shipped to the
>   customer, and his computer explodes.
>   Almost.
>
> The above regex turns ugly when the y
>   is missing from the subject string.
>   When y fails, the regex engine
>   backtracks. The group has one
>   iteration it can backtrack into. The
>   second x+ matched only one x, so it
>   can't backtrack. But the first x+ can
>   give up one x. The second x+ promptly
>   matches xx. The group again has one
>   iteration, fails the next one, and the
>   y fails. Backtracking again, the
>   second x+ now has one backtracking
>   position, reducing itself to match x.
>   The group tries a second iteration.
>   The first x+ matches but the second is
>   stuck at the end of the string.
>   Backtracking again, the first x+ in
>   the group's first iteration reduces
>   itself to 7 characters. The second x+
>   matches xxx. Failing y, the second x+
>   is reduced to xx and then x. Now, the
>   group can match a second iteration,
>   with one x for each x+. But this
>   (7,1),(1,1) combination fails too. So
>   it goes to (6,4) and then (6,2)(1,1)
>   and then (6,1),(2,1) and then
>   (6,1),(1,2) and then I think you start
>   to get the drift.
>
> If you try this regex on a 10x string
>   in RegexBuddy's debugger, it'll take
>   2558 steps to figure out the final y
>   is missing. For an 11x string, it
>   needs 5118 steps. For 12, it takes
>   10238 steps. Clearly we have an
>   exponential complexity of O(2^n) here.
>   At 21x the debugger bows out at 2.8
>   million steps, diagnosing a bad case
>   of catastrophic backtracking.
>
> **RegexBuddy is forgiving in that it
>   detects it's going in circles**, and
>   aborts the match attempt. **Other regex
>   engines (like .NET) will keep going
>   forever**, while others will crash with
>   a stack overflow (like Perl, before
>   version 5.10). Stack overflows are
>   particularly nasty on Windows, since
>   they tend to make your application
>   vanish without a trace or explanation.
>   Be very careful if you run a web
>   service that allows users to supply
>   their own regular expressions. People
>   with little regex experience have
>   surprising skill at coming up with
>   exponentially complex regular
>   expressions.

I assume you are going to have to handle it in code. I'd suggest you contact the author of [Regexbuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) and ask what is needed to detect this scenario.

Comment: RegexBuddy uses its own Regex engine and supports all major Regex flavours. My guess is that it precomputes the no. of iterations/steps required and aborts the match when that number exceeds the maximum allowed by the program.

Comment: from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression : "(...)The third algorithm is to match the pattern against the input string by backtracking. This algorithm is commonly called NFA, but this terminology can be confusing. Its running time can be exponential, which simple implementations exhibit when matching against expressions like (a|aa)*b that contain both alternation and unbounded quantification and force the algorithm to consider an exponentially increasing number of sub-cases. (...)". It must be part of an explanation...

Answer (score -1):

In general, regular expressions can take longer than you expect. You should experiment with the regular expression hjusing a tool like Regulator.

Comment: in this case, the process time is infinite ! And without any out of memory or stack overflow exception

Comment: It's entirely possible that this Regex does not complete.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you have nested "loops" in your Regex, which make it terribly inefficient (so that it basically takes forever due to the complexity of the expression).

If you say what you would like to match, I can try to figure out a more efficient Regex for that.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me like its a case the regex match growing exponentially.  See the [BCL blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/02/10/370690.aspx).

Best solution is to set a timeout on the regex, no messing about with threads.

See here how to [strip out strings with timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Trouble is, the timeout feature wasn't introduced until .NET 4.5, and the OP said he's using 3.5.